# Having trouble accessing properties on IronPython class from C#

Tags: c#, python, dynamic, ironpython, scriptengine

I have some C# code that instantiates an IronPython class and runs some code from it.  The IronPython class in question implements an interface that was defined in C#.  It also defines some of its own properties.

I am having trouble accessing the properties that are defined by the class itself, and I was wondering if anyone knew how to do this?

Here is an example IronPython class:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Core')
from System import Tuple

class TestClass (ITestInterface):
    ExamplePropertyOne = System.Tuple[System.String, System.String]("Hello", "World!")

    def ExampleMethod(self, some_parameter):
        ...code...
```

I create a ScriptEngine object to use the IronPython class, like so:

```
Dictionary<string, object> options = new Dictionary<string, object>();
options["Debug"] = true;
var python_script_engine = Python.CreateEngine(options);
var python_script_scope = python_script_engine.CreateScope();
python_script_engine.ExecuteFile("my_python_class.py", python_script_scope);

//The class could have any name, so instead of requesting the class by name,
//I simply iterate through the items in the python file to find the items
//that implements the expected interface, like so:
var python_script_items = python_script_scope.GetItems();
python_script_items = python_script_items.Where(x => x.Value is IronPython.Runtime.Types.PythonType);

foreach (var item in python_script_items)
{
    System.Type item_type = (Type)item.Value;
    var implemented_interfaces = item_type.GetInterfaces();
    if (implemented_interfaces != null && implemented_interfaces.Length > 0)
    {
        if (implemented_interfaces.ToList().Contains(typeof(ITestInterface)))
        {
            var class_to_instantiate = item.Value;
            var class_instance = class_to_instantiate();

            ...code here to get properties of class...
        }
    }
}
```

Just as an FYI, in the foreach loop "item" is a KeyValuePair (a string is the key and a dynamic object is the value).  After iterating over many items, the if-statements succeed when we reach the correct key-value pair at which the key is "TestClass" (I've stepped through the code to make sure the if-statement is succeeding at the proper item).

Unfortunately, although we enter the if-statements with "TestClass" as the item's key, when I instantiate the class I don't seem to be able to view the properties that are declared on TestClass.  I can only see the methods that are implemented from ITestInterface.

I have tried the following, not knowing which would get me the correct result:

```
var list1 = Dynamic.GetMemberNames(class_instance);  //Using Dinamitey
var list2 = python_script_engine.Operations.GetMemberNames(class_instance);
var fields = item_type.GetFields();
var properties = item_type.GetProperties();
var attributes = item_type.CustomAttributes;
var attributes2 = item_type.GetCustomAttributes(false);
var members = item_type.GetMembers();
var var_names = python_script_scope.GetVariableNames();
```

None of the above return the property "ExamplePropertyOne" in their results, which is a member of "TestClass".  I can only see the implemented methods.  And of course the python_script_scope.GetVariableNames only returns info from the scope outside of the instantiated class.

So, any advice?  Why am I only able to see the interface members?  How can I access the class's properties?

Thanks for any help!